# Take the sum of a pyspark dataframe per column efficiently

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I work in Spark 1.6 (unfortunately). I have a dataframe with many columns with 0's and 1's as values. I want to take the percentage of 1's per column.
So I do:

```
rowsNum = dfBinary.count()
dfStat = dfBinary.select([(count(when(col(c) == 1 , c))/rowsNum).
alias(c) for c in dfBinary.columns])
```

Is there a more efficient way to do this? Maybe a built in function with sum per column (I did not find any though).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace `count` and division with `mean` to avoid additional data scan

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import mean

dfStat = dfBinary.select([
    (mean(when(col(c) == 1 , c))).
    alias(c) for c in dfBinary.columns])
```

but otherwise, it is as efficient as you can get.

Answer (score 1):

you can use sum() from functions module,

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import sum
dfBinary.select([(sum(c)/rowsNum).alias(c) for c in dfBinary.columns]).show()
```